# Jquery month and year picker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to the `web development`. Here, I am using the jquery `datePicker`. In this I have a input box and that user can s`elect only year and month and not date`. So, I used,

```
$('#' + duration[k]).datepicker({
                      format: 'MM yyyy',
                      viewMode: "months",
                      minViewMode: "months",
                    });
```

I did this, Here my input are getting created dynamically.

```
var duration = ["StartDuration", "EndDuration"];
    var commentText = document.createElement('input');
                            commentText.setAttribute("type", "text");
                            commentText.name = "month";
                            commentText.id = duration[k];
                            commentText.className = 'form-control';
                            commentText.rows = '3';
                            commentText.placeholder = "Enter" + " " + duration[k];
                            commentText.setAttribute("readOnly", "true");
                            commentText.setAttribute("ng-model", duration[k]);
```

Used for loop on the array and then created this input box. Now what happening is here, It gets datepicker but it is having a `date-month-year` . So, I want to have only year and month. Can any one pleas help me with this ?

Comment: Why are you tagged `angularjs`??

Comment: because he is using angularjs `commentText.setAttribute("ng-model", duration[k]);`

Comment: Actually I am using angularjs so I tagged

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dateformat like this : `dateFormat: 'MM yy'`

Check the example :

```js
$(function() {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<label for="startDate">Your Date :</label>
<input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/13732/)

Comment: Hey, your solution is working for me. thanks. ,Here I want to have the years in descending order . How can I do this ?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no option to order years.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    });
```

Jquery datepicker provides these two - changeMonth,changeYear property for it and make format like MM yy.